# Strip whitespaces after and before of a specific list of punctuation symbols

Tags: python

Although I found some references in StackOverflow, I am unable to write the correct regular expression to achieve my goal. I want to remove whitespaces before and after of specific punctuation symbols from a string in python.

I have a function as follows.

```
def modify_answers(answers):
    hyp = []
    for ans in answers:
        # remove whitespace before - / ? . ! ;
        newhyp = re.sub(r'\s([-/?.!,;](?:\s|$))', r'\1', ans)
        # remove whitespace after - / $ _
        newhyp = re.sub(r'', r'\1', newhyp)
        hyp.append(newhyp)
    return hyp
```

Some examples of what I want to achieve:

- "Tax pin number is 1 - 866 - 704 - 7388 ." ---> "Tax pin number is 1-866-704-7388."
- "No , emu is not protected in Victoria ." ---> "No, emu is not protected in Victoria."
- "Find is to lose as construct is to _ _ _ _ _ _ ." ---> "Find is to lose as construct is to ______."
- "$ 1,0 is equal to $ 1,0 ." ---> "$1,0 is equal to $1,0."

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, define a function that performs replacement:

```
import re

def replace(x):
    y, z = x.groups()
    if z in '-/?.!,;':
        y = y.lstrip()
    if z in '-/$_':
        y = y.rstrip()
    return y
```

The function takes a match pattern and performs replacement accordingly.

Now, define your pattern. You can pre-compile for efficiency.

```
p = re.compile(r'(\s*([-/?.,!$_])\s*)')
```

Call the compiled regex `sub` on each string with the callback defined earlier:

```
cases = [                               
    "Tax pin number is 1 - 866 - 704 - 7388 .",
    "No , emu is not protected in Victoria .",
    "Find is to lose as construct is to _ _ _ _ _ _ .",
    "$ 1,0 is equal to $ 1,0 ."]

repl = [p.sub(replace, c) for c in cases]
```

```
print (repl)
['Tax pin number is 1-866-704-7388.', 'No, emu is not protected in Victoria.', 
 'Find is to lose as construct is to ______.', '$1,0 is equal to $1,0.']
```

Comment: ';' should be a part of the `re.compile()` statement. right?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
import re

sentences = ["Tax pin number is 1 - 866 - 704 - 7388 .",
             "No , emu is not protected in Victoria .",
             "Find is to lose as construct is to _ _ _ _ _ _ .",
             "$ 1,0 is equal to $ 1,0 ."]


def modify_answers(answers):
    hyp = []
    for ans in answers:
        # remove whitespace before - / ? . ! ;
        new_hyp = re.sub(r'\s([/?.!;_-])(\s|$)', r'\1', ans)
        new_hyp = re.sub(r'\s(,)(\s|$)', r'\1 ', new_hyp)
        new_hyp = re.sub(r'(^|\s)(\$)(\s|$)', r' \2', new_hyp)
        hyp.append(new_hyp.strip())
    return hyp

for sentence in modify_answers(sentences):
    print(sentence)
```

**Output**

```
Tax pin number is 1-866-704-7388.
No, emu is not protected in Victoria.
Find is to lose as construct is to______.
$1,0 is equal to $1,0.
```

**Notes**

- The first regex substitutes any of `/?.!;_-` surrounded by whitespaces by only the symbol. The `-` symbol means a range inside `[]` so you must place it at the end.
- The second regex substitutes `,` surrounded by whitespaces by `,` (a comma followed by a whitespace)
- The third regex substitutes `$` surrounded by whitespaces by a `$` (a dollar sign preceded by space). In this regex you must reference the second group.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the pattern `r' (?=[-/?.!])|(?<=[-/$_]) '` with empty string using `re.sub`

```
>>> lst = ["Tax pin number is 1 - 866 - 704 - 7388 .",
...              "No , emu is not protected in Victoria .",
...              "Find is to lose as construct is to _ _ _ _ _ _ .",
...              "$ 1,0 is equal to $ 1,0 ."]
>>> 
>>> def modify_answers(answers):
...     ptrn = re.compile(r' (?=[-/?.!])|(?<=[-/$_]) ')
...     return [ptrn.sub('', answer) for answer in answers]
... 
>>> 
>>> pprint(modify_answers(lst))
['Tax pin number is 1-866-704-7388.',
 'No , emu is not protected in Victoria.',
 'Find is to lose as construct is to ______.',
 '$1,0 is equal to $1,0.']
```